# Insert id number instead of using Enum type - How much queries become slower?

Tags: mysql, enums

sorry for my english (I'm posting from Italy) and (if it's possible) answer me with simple language (thanks)

I want you to know that I'm not a professional programmer: I'm just a fan of programming.

Here's the problem:
I'm going to create a table with four fields that contain repetitions of 6, 20, 165  and about 500 possible values (all varchar within 10 an 50).

My first idea was to use four table with only a field (primary Key) and four one-to-many relationships.

Later I read about Enum type of data and looked for a way for using this solution (because I thought that using all these varchar will absorb many bytes).

I've read a lot of web pages on the advantages and disadvantages of the Enum type, but  I still have many doubts.

My problems with Enum type are:
1) I need never empty string (so I have to avoid any insert error by working in strict mode);
2) I'm afraid of possibles changing of the association between an Enum and the other data (for example if an Enum value disappear and I need to split Its data to the others)

So, I was scared by using Enum and I thought about using a third solution:

Given that the Enum type uses the numeric id of an array instead of a varchar, I thought about inserting an Id column (numeric) in the four tables and use the four Ids in the table with data instead of the string values.

And now the question:
Using this third way I'll need a very more complex query compared to using Enum for extraction of string data.
So I don't know which is best choice for save bytes without loosing time in extracting data.

Would you suggest me a choice?

How can I calculate the row limit beyond which a query will become sluggish?

Thanks in advance to anyone who will help me.

Comment: 1. Simplify the problem. 2. Provide an example (sqlfiddle?) of the simplified problem, TOGETHER WITH the desired result. 3. In general, avoid ENUM and SET datatypes. Their use is anathematic (Distante?) to the principle of SQL database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENUM type is suitable for storing small number of values that are not supposed to change.

Your scenario is pretty common and the standard practice is to create four reference tables each with an ID field and a string value field, and then store those IDs in your main table.

Defining foreign key constraints ensures data integrity, and with indices your queries will be fast, do not worry about that at all.

Queries will not be complex, just needing four joins. It is also possible to create a view to avoid repeating the joins in different queries.

This solution is more flexible and easier to manage or port.